# 'w' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

```
$ heroku config:set MONGODB_URI="my url";
```

in last part of mongodb Atlas url there is `"?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

and Heroku is telling 'w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What I must do, I am getting Heroku application error;

Answer (score 3):

If you set this environment variable via Heroku dasboard it will work. Go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ click your app, go to Settings --> Reveal Config Vars and add your variable.